# Are SQL Server data size (not type) differences converted?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

In Microsoft SQL Server, if I have a column of `VARCHAR(255)` and a column of `VARCHAR(511)` and compare the two columns in a query, does SQL Server have to implicitly convert the columns as it would if the were different data types?

I've checked the execution plan as well as the plan cache and cannot find any reference to an implicit conversion, but I'm having difficulty swallowing that SQL Server just handles it as well as if they were the same size.

Comment: Those are in fact different datatypes so yes an implicit conversion happens.

Comment: By default SQL Server will ignore spaces at the end of strings when comparing the two strings- it pads the shorter one with spaces before it does the compare. But I would love to hear more from Sean (a very knowledgeable SQL Server developer) why they are different datatypes.